# Error "FileNotFoundException" al enviar parametros con HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, c#, asp.net-web-api

Tengo mi servicio ASP.NET Web Api donde hago un login simple, la cual probé con Postman (de Google Chrome) y me devuelve el dato correctamente pero en Android me devuelve el error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException

**AsynTask:**

```
private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, LoginModel>
{
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    URL url = null;
    @Override
    protected  LoginModel doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.5:80/api/ventas/Login");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            //return "exception";
        }
        try {
            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;");
            conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Append parameters to URL
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("User", params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("Pass", params[1]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            // Open connection for sending data
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
           // return "exception";
        }

        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = conn.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(line + "");
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(finalJson);

            if(object.has("Message"))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                LoginModel objModel = new LoginModel();

                objModel.setIdEmpleado(object.getInt("IdEmpleado"));
                objModel.setNombres(object.getString("Nombres"));
                objModel.setUsuario(object.getString("Usuario"));
                objModel.setClave(object.getString("Clave"));

                return objModel;
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(conn != null)
            {
                conn.disconnect();
            }

            try {
                if(reader != null){reader.close();}

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return  null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( LoginModel loginModel) {
        super.onPostExecute(loginModel);

        if (loginModel != null)
        {

            datosUsuario.setNombre_usuario(loginModel.getUsuario());
            datosUsuario.setClave(loginModel.getClave());
            datosUsuario.setNombreCompleto(loginModel.getNombres());
            datosUsuario.setIdEmpleado(loginModel.getIdEmpleado());

            SharedPreferences 
                preferences 
                = getSharedPreferences("temp", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("username", datosUsuario.getNombre_usuario());
            editor.putString("clave", datosUsuario.getClave());
            editor.putString("nombres", datosUsuario.getNombreCompleto());
            editor.putInt("idempleado", datosUsuario.getIdEmpleado());
            editor.commit();
            openPrincipal();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Datos incorrectos" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Servicio:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Login(String User, String Pass)
{
    try
    {
        SombraEntities contexto = new SombraEntities();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(User) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Pass))
        {
            var data = new
            {
                Message = "No llegaron los datos."
            };

            return Json(data);
        }

        Usuario objusuario = (from data in contexto.Usuario
                              where data.User == User && data.Password == User
                              select data).SingleOrDefault();

        if (objusuario != null)
        {
            Empleado objempleado = objusuario.Empleado.FirstOrDefault();

            var data = new
            {
                IdEmpleado = objempleado.IdEmpleado,
                Nombres = objempleado.Nombres + " " + objempleado.Apellidos,
                Usuario = objempleado.Usuario.User,
                Clave = objempleado.Usuario.Password
            };

            return Json(data);
        }
        else
        {
            var data = new
            {
                Message = "Datos de Login Incorrectos"
            };

            return Json(data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Error en Debugger:**

[image: Error en Debugger]

Comment: Este problema es por tu URL, prueba que funcione con el navegador o con algún consumidor de servicios rest

Comment: si funciona, como mencione, lo estoy probando con Postman de chrome

Comment: y desde el dispositivo? intenta cargar el url desde el dispositivo

Comment: como inicializas el Asynctask @cristiangonzalez ?

Comment: asi lo inicializo :       username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        new AsyncLogin().execute(username,password);

Comment: Veo que es correcto, asegura uses el pwd y user correcto. Que sistema operativo tienes? Puedo ver una captura de los valores qu envias por post, claro proteges el user y password.

Comment: estoy en window 10 y habilite el iis para publicar mi servicio, crees q sea el win10?? xq tampoco puedo crear un apicontroller con el wizard en el visual studio. nose q hacer

Answer (score 0):

> en android me devuelve el error java.io.fileNotFoundException

¿Tienes declarado el permiso para permitir conexión a internet?:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

asegura el recurso se encuentre disponible:

http://192.168.1.5:80/api/ventas/Login

---

Comentas que lo probaste con Postman por lo tanto considerando que el recurso se encuentra, revisa si las propiedades que defines para la conexión son correctas, revisa la inicialización del Asynctask, debe recibir un array donde el primer elemento es es el usuario y el segundo es el password (Asegura los nombres de parámetros sean correctos):

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("User", params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("Pass", params[1]);
```

Comment: revise las propiedades y son iguales, asi inicializo el asyntask                                    username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim(); password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim(); new AsyncLogin().execute(username,password);

Comment: Alguna otra sugerencia? O creo otro servicio??